# Humorous short story about government agent tracking down unauthorized weather control

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In a future whether weather control is not only possible but inexpensive and easily done, it is unlawful to engage in it privately, but of course people do. A government agent is tasked with tracking them down.

The short story is a setup for a punchline:

> Everybody does something about the weather, but nobody talks about it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

["The Meddlers"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56940) by [C. M. Kornbluth](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?285), first published in [*Science Fiction Adventures*, September 1953](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?198753+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Science_Fiction_Adventures_v01n06_1953-09_cape1736#page/n57/mode/2up). You described it perfectly:

> When the farmers had recovered, a matter of twenty minutes or so, he tried to interrogate them but got nowhere. "Don't you realize," he asked silkily, "that there are regular channels through which you can petition for heavier rainfall or a changed barometric pressure or more sunlight hours? Don't you realize you're disrupting continental economy when you try to free-lance?"

The ending:

> Slobb mumbled sympathetically, and Reev Markon voiced the ancient complaint of his department: "The trouble with this job is, everybody does things about the weather, but nobody talks about it!"